# django not filter by category name

Tags: django

django cannot filter by category name in url

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWPyO.png)
[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eprnn.png)

**`models.py`**:

```
class CategoryPosts(models.Model):
    CategoryPostsName = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    CategoryPostsDes = models.CharField(max_length=400, default=None)
    CategoryPostsRev = models.Foreignkey(CategoryType, related_name='topics',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CategoryPostsimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images', default=None)
```

**`views.py`**:

```
def Category(request,Category_id):
    CategoryObj = CategoryType.objects.get(CategoryNameUrl=Category_id)
    posts = CategoryPosts.objects.all()
    print(posts)
    return render(request,'Category.html',{
        'cat':CategoryObj,
        'post':posts
    })
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kk5T.png)

[URL code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIL8C.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see this question named [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Additionally, some research would lead you two manual pages: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `Category` you can filter with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

def Category(request, Category_id):
    categoryObj = get_object_or_404(CategoryType, CategoryNameUrl=Category_id)
    posts = CategoryPosts.objects.filter(CategoryPostsRev=categoryObj)
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: @0xff3z: can you please include the code in the question [[edit]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69141087/edit) then other people with the same problem can search it, people with visual impairment can read it, etc.